# TypeError: b2a_base64() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not list Odoo

Tags: python, odoo-10

I've a XML output from

```
root = etree.tostring(xml)
```

This file generate a xml but inside a list, so when I need to put it down as attachment in Odoo

```
self.env['ir.attachment'].create({
                'name': 'NFe_Autorizada.xml',
                'type': 'binary',
                'datas': base64.encodestring(root),
                'datas_fname': 'NFe_Autorizada.xml',
                'res_model': 'invoice.eletronic',
                'res_id': self.id,
                'mimetype': 'application/xml'})
```

I got a error: `b2a_base64() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not list`

When I try to call buy str(root),  it`s works but then XML file converts to string with escape characters

How can I convert a list XML, to file XML?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this using:

```
result = str(root)
result = result.replace("['","")
result = result.replace("']","")
```

but I didnt like this solution...